# How to force ActiveRecord to open database in read-only mode?

Tags: activerecord, readonly

Is there a parameter to ActiveRecord::Base.configurations or establish_connection() that forcibly ensures NO write is possible to the database? (If it makes a difference it is a Heroku Postgres database)

An ancillary Sinatra app (using ActiveRecord 5.2) needs *strictly* read-only access to a Heroku Postgres database used by a primary app... eg, even if a code bug accidentally tries to write a change, we need it to fail.

The advice in several SO threads is to define a readonly? method as shown below.

It ALMOST works... with one important exception...

Although it does prevent a save or an update_attributes, it does NOT prevent an update_column from writing.

```
APP_DB_HASH = { 
  "appdb"=>
    { "adapter"=>"postgresql", 
      "encoding" => "unicode",
      "pool" => 5,
      "url"=> ENV["APP_DATABASE_URL"] },

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations["appdb"] = {
  :adapter  => APP_DB_HASH["appdb"]["adapter"],
  :encoding  => APP_DB_HASH["appdb"]["encoding"],
  :database => uri.path.gsub('/',''),
  :username => uri.user,
  :password => uri.password,
  :port => uri.port,
  :host => uri.host
}

class AppBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection configurations["appdb"]

  # THIS DOES NOT PREVENT update_column FROM WRITING TO DATABASE!
  def readonly?
    true
  end
end

class MyModel << AppBase
...
end
```

results:

```
> rec = MyModel.first.foo
# false

> rec.update_attributes foo: true
# GOOD: exception thrown, prevents write

> rec.foo = true
> rec.save
# GOOD: exception thrown, prevents write

> rec.update_column :foo, true
# FAIL: THE 'READONLY" DATABASE GETS WRITTEN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I only know the answer for Postgresql, but that appears to be what you're using.

The simple answer is (possibly in an initializer):

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY")
```

The way I use it is:

```rb
def with_read_only_connection(configuration)
  original_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(configuration)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY")
  yield
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(original_connection)
end
```

Here's an example use:

```
[5] pry(main)> with_read_only_connection(:development) do
[5] pry(main)*   User.count
[5] pry(main)* end
   (0.2ms)  SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY
   (96.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 24566

[6] pry(main)> with_read_only_connection(:development) do
[6] pry(main)*   User.first.update_attribute(:first_name, "Bob")
[6] pry(main)* end
   (0.2ms)  SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "first_name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["first_name", "Bob"], ["updated_at", "2019-04-06 13:14:12.270619"], ["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction
: UPDATE "users" SET "first_name" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3
from .../.bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:602:in `exec_prepared'
```

NB - It will only call the `SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS..` when it connects.

Comment: as soon as I can test it I will come back to accept, thank you

Comment: Seems like it works if executed in a console. But when put it in an initialzer, it has no effect. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question when I was trying to do execute (ActiveRecord) actions in a read-only environment. After I while, I realized that instead making the whole connection read-only with its session characteristics (as proposed above in the method `with_read_only_connection`), I could simply wrap everything in a transaction and roll it back after execution:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  # do your thing!
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
```

I hope this helps. And great thanks @jjthrash, for the tipp with `SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS`, I use this all the time when I am fiddling on production.

Comment: It's important to put the `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` in a `ensure` block.

Comment: not really actually. as far as i know the default behavior for any exception thrown is rollback. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking about a flow control being used in the block. If you absolutely want the rollback, I think that the `ensure` is the better way to enforce it.